# Javascript Promise Wont Resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I've written the following code but its going to reject instead of resolve callback.

```
(function() {
  var restante = 0;
  'use strict';

  function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(done, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (restante = 0) {
          done();
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  wait().
  then(function() {
    console.log("First Resolution");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("Error occured");
  });
})();
```

Why its going to reject every time?

Comment: You have a typo in the if statement.... `if (restante = 0)` should be `if (restante === 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an assignment instead of a comparison:

`if (restante = 0)`

Should be:

`if (restante === 0)`

https://jsfiddle.net/6nx92hhf/2/

Comment: Typo on my part :)

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

In your `if` statement it should be:

```
if (restante == 0) {
    done();
}
```

**OR** *(Better practice)*

```
if (restante === 0) {
    done();
}
```

Your full code will look like this:

```
(function() {
  var restante = 0;
  'use strict';

  function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(done, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (restante == 0) {
          done();
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  wait().
  then(function() {
    console.log("First Resolution");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("Error occured");
  });
})();
```

Conditional statements require `==` (or `===`) while assigning statements contain the single `=`.